# gridster: Can you limit the touchable area of a widget to a specific area?

Tags: jquery, gridster

The canonical use of gridster seems to be one where the entire object can be touched to indicate that a drag operation is to be started.  Is it possible to limit that touchable region to a specific area (div) in the object, perhaps indicated by an icon of some sort?  I'd like to be able to use gridster with objects that have other (mouse-sensitive) things in them, and I don't want the user (let along gridster :) getting confused about what's supposed to happen.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Followup: If you've seen Things on the Mac, this is the kind of thing I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved: the `draggable` config option can take a `handle` option, which specifies the thing to serve as the handle.  cf. https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/pull/59

Comment: Yup; thanks; forgot to come back to do it after the SO-imposed delay.